# jquery switch case background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use jquery to change the background to a new URL based on a javascript switch case. I've done 3 things:

1) Have this in my HTML doc:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

2) Structure my Switch case (which I know is being called) in HTML doc like so:

```
function calcBackground() {
switch(counter) {
case 1:
    $('body').toggleClass('background1');
    break;
case 2:
    $('body').toggleClass('background2');
    break;
case 3:
    $('body').toggleClass('background3');
    break;
default:
    //nothing of note here
}
}
```

3) Put this in my CSS:

```
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image:url('http://hdwallpicture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Blue-Widescreen-HD-Wallpapers.jpg');
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

body.background1 {
  background-image:url('http://hdwallpicture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Blue-Widescreen-HD-Wallpapers.jpg');
}

body.background2 {
  background-image:url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-vmh1i-b3XNY/T9iTjPGKYZI/AAAAAAAAFwo/jv3Yysxcl9Q/s1600/Blue-wallpaper-23.jpg');
}

body.background3 {
  background-image:url('http://wallpaper4god.com/wallpapers/blue_1269_1076x768.jpg');
}
```

Note: The URL for body.background1 is the same as the default URL background for the page intentionally. The backgrounds aren't changing upon the switch statement being called though.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: where is `counter` set? I imagine your switch is going into the `default`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never removing any classes... If this is like a slideshow, you'll eventually end up with the body having all three classes.

Try this:

```
function calcBackground() {
    switch (counter) {
        $('body').removeClass('background1 background2 background3');
        case 1:
            $('body').addClass('background1');
            break;
        case 2:
            $('body').addClass('background2');
            break;
        case 3:
            $('body').addClass('background3');
            break;
        default:
            //nothing of note here
    }
}
```

Comment: only problem is that it seems to take a long time (several seconds) to load each URL/picture. any ideas how to improve performance for this?

Comment: You could preload the images. There are plenty of resources available on how to do that.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Yeah because once I've cycled through once, they load in a blink the second time around. I'll search around for how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I see no `counter`, so I can only assume it's not set. A function like this would be much cleaner:

```
function calcBackground() {
    if(typeof counter !== 'undefined'){
        $('body').removeClass('background1 background2 background3')
                 .addClass('background' + counter);
    }
}
```

or, if your body has (and will **never**) have any other classes:

```
function calcBackground() {
    if(typeof counter !== 'undefined'){
        $('body').attr('class', 'background' + counter);
    }
}
```